# Can we use only HTTP POST and and get rid of HTTP GET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-get

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am using http `POST` for custom validation. Recently I learned that both http `POST` and http `GET` are used to send data to the server. HTTP `POST` is more secure while http `GET` is less secure as it sends the data in the query string.

I want to know then, is it possible to get completely rid of HTTP `GET` in my project as its function is similar to http `POST`? I tried that but it immediately gave error as soon as I started debugging the project. It said "The resource cannot be found.". I am confused. Please help.

Comment: Can you post how you tried to get rid of GET requests?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to review Http Methods - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Since you just started the right course of action would be to use GET to obtain the data (e.g. load the form) and POST to update the data (submit the form to the server).

If the application you are working on is written in plain ASP.NET MVC it will be impossible to completely avoid GET (as it is used by the browser to load application pages/views).

Once you are ready to move to REST APIs you might want to deeper explore PUT, DELETE and other methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you elaborate on that

Comment: What I meant is that GET requests are perfectly normal and it is fine to have them BUT you nee to make sure GET requests don't change any data (unless you track things like last activity, etc.). When you load an edit form in ASP.NET MVC it is normal to use GET requests to load its initial view with data displayed. On form submit you can make POST requests to update it.

Comment: Browser by default uses GET to load the page - that's most likely why you are getting 404 error above when you are trying to open a page (a.k.a. call controller action) that doesn't support GET. The only workaround I can think of is to convert the app to SPA (e.g. Angular app) - that way you can load all the necessary resources using GET and then make POST requests to load/create data and PUT/DELETE, to modify/delete. Even in this case I would recommend to still use GET for obtaining data from the server as it complies with REST methodology